# Random numbers and getStdGen

Tags: haskell, monads

From the Haskell wikibook we have:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import System.Random

type GeneratorState = State StdGen

rollDie :: GeneratorState Int
rollDie = do
  generator <- get
  let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
  put newGenerator
  return value
```

If we execute:

```
evalState rollDie (mkStdGen 0)
```

then we get a return type of Int.

This much I understand, but I am wondering if it is possible to wire into this logic the use of the system generator accessed by the function getStdGen. The getStdGen function operates in the IO monad, and my question is (surely this must be the MOST often asked Haskell question) how can you get the generator out of the IO context to use in the non IO monad code above?

Apologies for the newbie question. I am aware that one should not use unsafePerformIO, but otherwise perplexed.

Comment: What you want is probably the `MonadRandom` class (in `Control.Monad.Random`). If you write a function of type `MonadRandom m => m Int`, then you can instantiate it with `IO Int`, which would use `getStdGen`, or `Rand Int` (Rand is a special monad for generating random numbers, essentially the same as State StdGen), which you can use as you have. The simplest solution, however, is `evalState rollDie \`fmap\` getStdGen`, which simply applies the function `evalState rollDie` to the `StdGen` created by `getStdGen`.

Comment: Is this question about random numbers at all out is it about IO and how to use bind?

Answer (score 1):

The core of the matter is that it's impossible to produce random numbers out of thin air. You either seed a generator with some input (that's what you do with `mkStdGen 0`), or you can take the system one with `getStdGen`.

The problem with `mkStdGen 0` is that it's a constant, so your stream of random numbers will show its pseudo-randomness very clearly by being a constant too.

The problem with `getStdGen` is that it's in the IO monad.

You can't get the generator out of IO to use in a pure computation, that's the whole point of making IO a monad.  But within IO, you can bind it using the normal do-notation:

```
main = do
  gen <- getStrGen
  print $ evalState rollDie gen
```

Of course, it'll only produce unique results once.

I heartily concur with [the comment recommending MonadRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674836/random-numbers-and-getstdgen#comment43765957_27674836). I've been using it for my random-based computations since I found out about it, and haven't looked back.